# Redux-thunk and redux-promise: empty payload in PENDING state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise-middleware

So I have `redux-thunk` set up and when I call the `updateUser(userInfos)` action, it returns a promise to update the server with those infos.

But sequentially I need to update the local state with those infos too, and if I wait for `UPDATE_USER_FULFILLED`, the *effect* of my action is not instantaneous, which feels weird for the user.

I thought of reducing the `UPDATE_USER_PENDING` action to update the local state *before* the server response arrives with up-to-date data (which should be the same so no re-rendering), **but** unfortunately, the `payload` of `UPDATE_USER_PENDING` action is `null` :(

Ain't there a way to load it with some data, which would allow instant UI response before server return?

Could be something like:

```
export function updateUser(user) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: {
      promise: userServices.update(user),
      localPayload: user,
    }
  }
}
```

but I'm guessing this is not available?

For now, the only solution I see is to create a `UPDATE_USER_LOCAL` action which would do the local action in parallel with the server call. But this is not very elegant and much heavier.

Thanks for the help

Comment: looks like the redux toolkit stores it in the `action.meta.arg` property instead of `action.payload`